# X server: in-container development in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron, vscode-remote, xserver

I'd like to debug a desktop application (notably, [this one, based on electron](https://github.com/TomoyukiAota/photo-location-map) ) using VSCode's in-container feature.

For this purpose, I'm using this `dockerfile`:

```
FROM electronuserland/builder:wine-chrome

# Create the user and assign grants
ARG USERNAME=electron
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --shell /bin/bash --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y sudo \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME

USER $USERNAME
```

With this in place, I can successfully build the application (using `sudo npm ci`) and create the Windows binaries (using `sudo npm run package:windows`).

Unfortunately, if I attempt to run a debug session with `sudo npm start`, I get:

```
✔ Compiled successfully.
[1023/144902.115440:FATAL:electron_main_delegate.cc(299)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
/.../node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGTRAP
```

On the other hand, if I attempt to run a debug session without `sudo`, that is, launching `npm start`, I get this:

```
✔ Compiled successfully.
[22189:1023/151033.444880:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(157)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /.../node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.
/.../node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGTRAP
[22205:0100/000000.493074:ERROR:zygote_linux.cc(661)] write: Broken pipe (32)
ERROR: "electron:serve" exited with 1.
```

The "start" script in `package.json` is this:

```
"start": "npm-run-all -p ng:serve electron:serve",
```

What configuration is missing (and where!) to make the whole thing work?

**NOTES:**

- Attempting to apply ownership and grants to `chrome-sandbox` like this:

  ```bash
  sudo chown root /.../node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox 
  sudo chmod 4755 /.../node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox
  ```

  just yields to another error:

  ```
  Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
  ```

/workspaces/photo-location-map/node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGTRAP
ERROR: "electron:serve" exited with 1.